# Variable is not defined for module library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been refactoring my App.js file and taking some functions out into a file called utilities.js. Each function has an export and my App.js has the requisite import. However, I am getting some `'myVariable' is not defined` errors for the utilities.js file. I figure this is because I am declaring the variable outside of the App() function in my App.js file, and so if you look at the utilities.js file in isolation, the variables haven't been declared. This pieceTable variable is also used in other functions in App.js.

How do you deal with this situation?

Example:

utilities.js file

```
export const findPieces = piece => {
pieceTable = [];
// blah blah
}
```

App.js file

```
import {findPieces} from './utilities'

let pieceTable=[];

function App() {
const findDraught = findPieces('King')
}
```

I get a "Failed to compile" error for this type of scenario, saying 'pieceTable' is not defined in utilities.js

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: I've done that now.

Comment: you are doing wrong in utilities.js

Comment: cont pieceTable = [] is corect in utilities.js

Comment: But pieceTable is a global variable also used in other functions in the App.js file. Won't that have an impact?

Comment: in that case you need to export from app.js and import in utilities.js

Comment: Export what from App.js?

Comment: export const pieceTable = []

Comment: Thanks for that. I have worked out something else. My functions are not pure. I need to pass in the pieceTable as an argument, and it avoids all these issues.

Comment: Your example where `findPieces` actually **assigns** a new value to `pieceTable` is confusing.  I feel like your intent was that the example should **use** the existing value of `pieceTable`.  e.g. with something like `pieceTable.find( /* blah blah blah */ )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If you actually want a global

When you say `let pieceTable=[];` you are explicitly making `pieceTable` a variable with scope local to the module, i.e. **not** a global.

If you had just referred to `pieceTable` you would be assigning a property to the top-level scope object which is `window` (in a browser JavaScript context).  You can refer to it explicitly with: `window.pieceTable`.

(FYI, in node.js it would be `global.pieceTable`. [Read why](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global).)

Globals are passé and I don't recommend using one in your case.

#### If you don't want a global, but you still want modular design

Choose an owning module for `pieceTable` and have that module **export** it.  Then have every other module that needs to refer to `pieceTable` **import** it.  This is making use of the *module* mechanism rather than the *global* mechanism.

#### If you want *pure* design

Design your functions so that they are passed in the value of `pieceTable` (or an object that has `pieceTable` as a property) as an argument to the function rather than relying on getting a singleton or global.  This will make your functions easier to test as well and eliminate confusing global side effects.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I have refactored a lot of code now, and I am finding that to keep my functions pure, I have to pass in a ton of arguments. Then again, I presume that is the price to pay.

Answer (score 0):

My functions are not pure. I need to pass in the pieceTable as an argument when calling it, and it avoids all these issues. Don't have my utilities.js file rely on global variables in another file. Pass in arguments to these utility functions instead.

Comment: you should use react-redux

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not defined in `utilities.js` because there's not a `let` or `const`.

If you don't want to redefine it in the utilities function, then you need to pass in the `pieceTable` when you call `findPieces`.